# Full wave bridge rectifier

Tags: bridge-rectifier

Where should the ground be placed in a full wave bridge rectifier ? I mean if the ground was placed at one end of the load resistor, then won't the other diode (which would be forward biased in one cycle) that leaves from that point( point of contact of the resistor and ground) be cut off since that diode is not having a forward voltage of 0.7 volts ?

Comment: Briefly, no. You can put ground wherever you like. Voltage is relative.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. That was a new knowledge for me that u could put ground anywhere in the circuit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a common ground between input and output of a bridge rectifier (or you will short out diodes and Bad Things will happen).

So, ground either the input or the output or neither, depending on safety and other requirements, but never both.

Comment: Good answer. I really appreciate that answer. Thanks Spehro Pefhany :)

Comment: Agreed!  I blew the circuit breaker in our part of the building by connecting the on-board ground with my laptop's ground via a programming header.  Lesson learned!